# Error: Invalid length parameter passed to LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, substring

I want to remove the first five characters of `ProductName` from `dataGridview`.
`ProductName` length is at least 8 characters.

I do not want to display the first five chracters. When I load the form, I use this method. But this givs me "Error: Invalid length parameter passed to LEFT or SUBSTRING function", please Help! Thank you.

```
private void LoadProducts()
{
    try
    {
        db = new Db();
        var gridvResult = (from u in db.Products
                           join c in db.Categories on u.CatId equals c.CategoryId 
                           select new
                           {
                               PrId = u.ProductId, 
                               ProductName =  u.ProductName.Substring(5), // Here I get error
                               CategoryName = c.CategoryName,                                           
                           }).ToList();

        if (gridvResult != null)
        {
            dgvProduct.DataSource = null;
            dgvProduct.DataSource = gridvResult;
            dgvProduct.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        Exception inner = ex.InnerException;
        while (inner != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(inner.Message);
            inner = inner.InnerException;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `ProductName`'s length is less than 5 chars or empty? Check the length before `SubString`ing it. `u.ProductName.Length > 5 ? u.ProductName.Substring(5) : u.ProductName`. I'ld suggest to consider to format that string in the DGV's  [CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting) event.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you, One of my 50 productName was short .. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void LoadProducts()
{
    try
    {
        db = new Db();
        var gridvResult = (from u in db.Products
                       join c in db.Categories on u.CatId equals c.CategoryId 
                       select new
                       {
                           PrId = u.ProductId, 
                           //ProductName =  u.ProductName.Substring(5), // Here I get error
                           ProductName = u.ProductName.Length > 5 ? u.ProductName.Substring(5) : u.ProductName;
                           CategoryName = c.CategoryName,                                           
                       }).ToList();

        if (gridvResult != null)
        {
            dgvProduct.DataSource = null;
            dgvProduct.DataSource = gridvResult;
            dgvProduct.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        Exception inner = ex.InnerException;
        while (inner != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(inner.Message);
            inner = inner.InnerException;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep coding!